# UnsupportedClassVersionError when running java program

Tags: java

My java program was compiled succesfully. But when I tried to run I got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: hello :
        Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
Could not find the main class: hello. Program will exit.
```

Comment: have you got any hello.class files in the directory where you compiled java code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to use two **different java versions** for **compiling** and **running** the program, like 1.8 and 1.6, with the compiler being much more recent.

Could be that the JDK used is in path after a JRE of a different version. Take a look at

`echo $PATH`

and

`type  javac`
`type  java`

`javac -version`
`java -version`

---

For example, if you have the following versions:
`javac 1.7.0_55` and
`java 1.6.0_31`, 
you could either put JDK/JRE 1.7 in $PATH before 1.6 - to compile and run with 1.7;
or get a 1.6 JDK and put that in $PATH before the JDK you currently use - to compile and run with 1.6.

Comment: javac -version
javac 1.7.0_55
java -version
java version "1.6.0_31"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.3) (6b31-1.13.3-1ubuntu1~0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)             yes they are different.Now what should I do

Comment: @SowmyaRavichandran Either put 1.7 in $PATH before 1.6 - to compile and run with 1.7; or get a 1.6 JDK and put that in $PATH before the JDK you currently use - to compile and run with 1.6.

Comment: @SowmyaRavichandran Glad to help - you should "accept" the answer with the checkmark if it solved the problem, and maybe upvote it. (Otherwise it will technically stay unanswered forever)